# How to make chrome to not "unselect" in addressbar

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I have the following strange behavior - when I click on address-bar, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd>, the selection disappears after very short time, I could not find what causing that. Same happen if I just select text with mouse or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys.

Chrome version 24.0.1312.5 beta - Linux.

chromium acting same.

Comment: What happens when you press `ctrl+L` combination?

Comment: all line selected and stay selected, the issue appears to be annoing when i trying to remove tail  of the URL, or when I want to select part of the address

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem reproducible on another Linux machine, or another browser (example: `Firefox`) on your machine?

Note that text selection problems on Linux sometimes could be due to X or your window manager's configuration. One common source of problem is a [failing mouse](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11487845).

If you can reproduce this problem, have a quick [search on a list of related Chrome issues](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=label:Area-UI%20text%20selection%20feature=Omnibox&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary), then [log a new issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) with the Chromium team.

Comment: seems it was due to parcellite (clipboard manager), i think q-n should be closed a localised